# Problem to install a older version of angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v8

I need to install a older version of angular cli.
When I use:

```
npm install -g angular-cli@8.3.23
```

This error appears:

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for angular-cli@8.3.23.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

My old node version is v12.14.1

What I can do to install this version of angular-cli?

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.23`?

Answer (score 1):

You're spelling the npm package incorrectly.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.23
```

Note the `@` in the front.

Comment: Haha, that's what you get for copying the question over :D Thanks!

Comment: It's a spelling error. Just vote to close.

Comment: Been there, done that already.

Comment: So, you voted to close *and* you answered the post?